# How to pause a for loop until a button is presses?

Tags: java, android, loops, firebase

I have a loop in my android application which downloads the images from online database i.e. firebase database. I get this data in a Datasnapshot object that is further used in loop to load images from firebase storage. The loop runs too fast and i could only see the last image. i want each new image to be loaded in image viewer when a button is clicked. how can i achieve this. Using loop within a loop makes my program to go to hang state.

Answer (score 0):

may be you could implement it in producer and consumer.for example.

```
    Object lock = new Object();
    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    });
    for (; ; ) {
        synchronized (lock){
            try {
                lock.wait();
                //do your work here
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use a library like Ion. It makes it very easy to load ImagViews asynchronically.

Here is the link to github.

[Ion Library](https://github.com/koush/ion)

To perform the action upon clicking on a button, you can request the download from within an onClickListener() set to the button.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new ViewOnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
      <here you fire your download>
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the Semaphore with size of 1 and aquire a lock in your loop and release the lock on your button click. Of course your image loading has to be in a background thread.